# What does "shortening" mean? Is it different from "abbreviation"?

Tags: meaning, differences, abbreviations

What does *shortening* mean? Is it different from *abbreviation*? I checked the dictionary, but I don't get the difference clearly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact shortening is a kind of abbreviation.

According to [MSN Dictionary](http://dictionary.msn.com/) There are **four main kinds of abbreviations**:

- **Shortenings** of words usually consist of the first few letters of the full form and are usually spelled with a final period when they are still regarded as abbreviations

> *cont. = continued*
>
> *bus = omnibus*
>
> *taxi = taxicab*
>
> *zoo = zoological garden*
>
> *bike = bicycle*

- **Contractions** are abbreviated forms in which letters from the middle of the full form have been omitted.

> *Dr. = doctor*
>
> *St. = saint or street*
>
> *can't = cannot*
>
> *didn't = did not*

- **Initialisms** are made up of the initial letters of words and are pronounced as separate letters.

> *CIA (or C.I.A.)*
>
> *NYC*
>
> *pm (or p.m.)*
>
> *U.S. (or US)*

- **Acronyms** are initialisms that have become words in their own right, or similar words formed from parts of several words. **They are pronounced as words rather than as a series of letters.**

> *AIDS*
>
> *laser*
>
> *scuba*
>
> *UNESCO*

Please Visit this [link](http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=abbreviation) to read more about abbreviation.

Answer (score 7):

Shortening also refers to [fats used for baking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortening).  Probably not what you meant, though. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I was not looking for this meaning but I didn't know that.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing as you.

Comment: @Will: same here. I initially thought the OP wanted to be clear on the difference between those two meanings!

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=shortening :)

Comment: And shortening actually abbreviates gluten molecules :)

Answer (score 3):

I have been shortening the legs on my table, but I have not been abbreviating them!