# Can "sitcom" be considered an "acronym"? A Syllabic Acronym? Or a Hybrid Acronym?

Tags: acronyms, clipping

> ACRONYM - An abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acronym

Much has been written about acronyms and abbreviations here at EL&U. See  [Difference between an acronym and abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation) However, I see no mention to this type of acronym where the first half of a word is joined to the second half of another.

> Sitcom - a situation comedy, certainly doesn't fulfill the classic criterion for an acronym.  But it might be a variety and might be called by a diferent name. Is it?

Comment: I would call it a "double truncation," since it reduces two whole words to the first syllable of each.

Comment: Nope. It's called an abbreviation, contraction, a shortening, or even a [clipped form](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/contractions). Wiki says   [sitcom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitcom) is a shortening.

Comment: Related: *[How can I tell when an abbreviation is an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31864)*, *[Difference between an acronym and abbreviation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755)*, *[What does “shortening” mean? Is it different from “abbreviation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12910)*.

Comment: @medica Could you show me exactly where words like "sitcom" are mentioned in the above link ?  Or where a definition that fits it is given?

Comment: Good to see you had already made your mind up.

Comment: @Luis - "An acronym... is simply a word formed by taking letters (*usually* the first) of each word in a phrase to form an abbreviation". [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/what-does-shortening-mean-is-it-different-from-abbreviation) answer is also good. It doesn't need to have the word *sitcom* to address your question, which is about acronyms.

Comment: However, Mari-Lou's answer is worth having on record for future reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, *sitcom* can be considered an acronym.

The ODO definition is a bit too restrictive, if you ask me.

Compare it to the OED, which has two distinct senses of the word: the first is identical to *initialism* (i.e., when each letter in the acronym is pronounced individually); the [second](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844) is:

> A word formed from the initial letters of other words **or (occas.) from the initial parts of syllables taken from other words**, the whole being pronounced as a single word (such as NATO, RADA). *[My emphasis]*

The [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym) is also more inclusive:

> a word (as NATO, radar, or laser) formed from the initial **letter or letters** of each of the successive parts or major parts of a compound term

Both these definitions tally with the very first two sentences in the [Wikipedia article on acronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym):

> An acronym is an abbreviation formed from the initial components in a phrase or a word. These components may be individual letters (as in *laser*) or parts of words (as in *Benelux* and *Ameslan*).

All this does not mean that ‘acronym’ is the first thing people think of when they hear *sitcom*—it is an **option**, but I would not call it the ideal description. *Sitcom* is a more typical case of [blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word), so if you are simply looking for a word to describe *sitcom* (rather than specifically wondering whether you can describe it as an acronym), I would use that instead.

Comment: The ODO definition is not identical to _initialism_. The difference is how the result is pronounced. If you say each letter separately, like `CPU`, it's an initialism. If you speak it as a normal word, like `RADAR`, it's an acronym.

Comment: @Barmar I never said the ODO definition is identical to _initialism_. I said it is too restrictive. The first of the two definitions given by the OED is identical to _intialism_ (which I defined the same way you just did), but I did not quote that definition, only the second one.

Comment: Sorry, got confused over what you were referring to.

Comment: Hmmm, your recent edit "*Yes, sitcom can be considered an acronym*" changes your original position fairly radically. I wouldn't have bothered doing all that research if you had stated this from the beginning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, didn't mean to cause you unnecessary work. It was your answer, though, that made me realise that I had perhaps answered the question a bit too literally, thinking only of whether _sitcom_ **could** be considered an acronym, and completely neglecting to mention whether it **should**. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the dictionaries here. Benelux isn't an arconym, and neither is sitcom. I can't imagine anyone I've ever known who would agree. Abbreviation, yes - acronym, no.

Answer (score 7):

*Sitcom* is defined as a **shortening** by

> - [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sitcom)
>     n. *Informal*. situation comedy. [1960–65; by shortening]
> - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitcom)
>     A situation comedy, often shortened to the portmanteau sitcom
> - [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sitcom)
>     *noun*, Informal. 1. situation comedy. 1960-65; by shortening

Or as an **abbreviation** by

> - [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sitcom)
>     **Origin** 1960s: abbreviation.
> - [Reverso Dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/sitcom)
>     A sitcom is an amusing television drama series about a set of
>     characters. *Sitcom* is an abbreviation for `situation comedy'

Or simply **short for** by

> - [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sitcom)
>     *Sitcom is short for “situation comedy.”*

Or a **clipped form** as described by Prof. Larry Trask

> Contractions must be carefully distinguished from [clipped forms](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/contractions). A
>   **clipped form** is a full word which happens to be derived by chopping a
>   piece off a longer word, usually one with the same meaning. 
>   *Clipped forms* are very common in English; here are a few, with their related
>   longer forms:
>
> gym_____gymnasium
>   ad ______advertisement
>   pro _____professional
>   deli _____delicatessen
>   hippo ____hippopotamus  (etc.)

Or as a **clipping** by Wikipedia

> In linguistics, [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(morphology)) is the word formation process which consists in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand: 1969). Clipping is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."
>   Clipping mainly consists of the following types:
>
> Back clipping
>   Fore-clipping
>   Middle clipping
>   Complex clipping
>
> [...]
>
> **Complex Clipping**
>
> Clipped forms are also used in compounds. One part of the original
>   compound most often remains intact. Examples are: *cablegram* (cable
>   telegram), *op art* (optical art), *org-man* (organization man), *linocut*
>   (linoleum cut). Sometimes both halves of a compound are clipped as in
>   *navicert* (navigation certificate). In these cases it is difficult to
>   know whether the resultant formation should be treated as a clipping
>   or as a blend, for the border between the two types is not always
>   clear. According to Bauer (1983), the easiest way to draw the
>   distinction is to say that those forms which retain compound stress
>   are *clipped compounds*, whereas those that take simple word stress are
>   not. By this criterion *bodbiz*, *Chicom*, *Comsymp*, *Intelsat*, *midcult*,
>   *pro-am*, *photo op*, *sci-fi*, and ***sitcom*** are all compounds made of
>   clippings.

Comment: All acronyms are abbreviations and/or shortenings; _acronym_ is just a more precise subtype of abbreviation. I can’t quite figure out why, but Wikipedia’s description of _sitcom_ as a portmanteau word jars with me. I can’t get myself to think of it as a portmanteau, no matter how I try. Had it been called a _situdy_ or _sitmedy_ or something like that, that would have been an obvious portmanteau, but taking the beginnings of two words … that just doesn’t feel right for portmanteaus.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I found many references which do **not** say *sitcom* is an acronym, and many dictionaries who do not make any distinction.

Comment: Many of these abbreviating methods overlap. The fact that _sitcom_ is a shortening does not prevent it from being also definable as an acronym. Acronym is perhaps not the first way I would have thought of to define it either (I would go with _blend_ if I were to give it the most appropriate name); but it certainly does fall within the scope of what an acronym can be. I doubt there are any references that specifically say that _sitcom_ is not an acronym (as opposed to not saying that it is)—I would find that odd.

Comment: +1 for unearthing Bauer’s very useful distinction (which I had not seen before)!

Comment: Tom McArthur says there are three types of acronyms: letter acronyms, syllabic acronyms, and hybrids.  According to his view, "sitcom" belongs to the second type.  (The Oxford Companion to the English Language, Oxford University Press, 1992)

Comment: @medica  I did upvote Mari-Lou's answer, although what it shows now is not what it showed when I first read it.  It has been edited and improved.  At the time I marked Janus's answer, her answer didn't show here, on my screen, half of what it is now.  Anyway, I hope everyone here shares your concern: "It seems a bit unfair to make someone do so much work" and ignore it.

Comment: @Luis You accepted Janus's answer less than one hour after you had posted your question. I was clearly adding extra information with every edit, as I knew time was of essence and I was right. Anyone could have seen that, check the history. I was making a point and looking for references. In the end, you preferred Janus's answer which is fair enough, but it's clear to me you weren't interested in hearing an opinion that contrasted your preconceived one.

Comment: @luis just for the record I added this [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/can-sitcom-be-considered-an-acronym/193830#comment406015_193827): *Good to see you had already made your mind up* 17 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

The word *sitcom* is a [**portmanteau**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of *situation* and *comedy*.

Comment: Independently from the fact that the Wikipedia link I posted and cited from contained the expression, *portmanteau*, I don't believe it to be an accurate description  if we take the definition of portmanteau to be: **"A portmanteau word fuses both the sounds and the meanings of its components, as in smog, coined by blending smoke and fog, or motel, from motor and hotel**. *In linguistics, a portmanteau is defined as a single morph which represents two or more morphemes."* as reported in the Wikipedia link you posted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm curious which part of the Wikipedia definition you feel fits _sitcom_ poorly.  Fusing-sounds, check.  Fusing meanings, check.  Blending two words, check.  Admittedly not a _single morph_, but then neither is _motel_.  The requirement that a portmanteau be a single morph is highly arguable.

Comment: Sitcom is hardly a fusing sound, they're staccato from each other.