# Acronym or abbreviation?

Tags: acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between an acronym and abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation)

My question refers to the term/word ET. Some dictionaries define it as acronym standing for "extra terrestrial" and others say it is an abbreviation for extraterrestrial.

Could ET be both an acronym *and* an abbreviation?

Comment: Related: [Difference between an acronym and an abbreviation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation).

Comment: According to @Alenanno's linked question, ET is an acronym.

Comment: The linked question is indeed related, but does not cover the issue raised by _ET_, which includes whether an abbreviation which is formed from non-initial parts of a word is an acronym.

Comment: I think the problem here is not that this isn't a duplicate but that the accepted answer to the original question is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

No, *ET* (or E.T.) is not an acronym by most all definitions (although it is an abbreviation).  An acronym is formed from the initial letters of several words of a phrase.  There is some dispute as to whether to qualify as an acronym, the set of letters has to be able to be pronounced phonetically (like *radar*) or can be pronounced by pronouncing the letters (like *IBM*).

In the case of ET, it is an abbreviation of *extraterrestrial*, a single word, so an acronym of it would be only the single letter *E*.   If ET were an acronym, it would stand for *extra terrestrial* (which if it were understood, would mean something like "an unneeded earth being").

Comment: E.T. is styled as *E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial* not *ET the Extraterrestrial*.  It is clearly an acronym.  I agree however, that this is non-standard.

Comment: Sorry my bad it is an initialism.

Comment: The fact that both *extraterrestrial* and *extra-terrestrial* are used puts this one in the grey area. $SETI$ in *The SETI League* is officially *Search(ing) for Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence*; it’s pronounced ['sɛtɪ] and is by any reasonable standard an acronym. A little searching readily turns up other instances of *extra-terrestrial*, e.g., by the Royal Society and by Arthur C. Clarke.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation), an abbreviation is any form of word-shorting (or phrase-shorting) using  any method, including acronyms (E.T.) and initialisms (e.g. BBC, ABC, etc).