# Another word for Short form and its Long form of a word

Tags: word-choice

Based on the following example:

```
Local Area Network (LAN)
```

You can say that LAN is the short form and the Local Area Network is the long form.

What is the another word for "short form"? (Is 'acronym' a better word for replacing 'short term'? or 'abbreviation' would be a better choice?)

What is the another word for "long form"? (Would 'backronym' a better word choice to replace 'long form'?)

I am open for other word choice to replace 'short form' and 'long form'. Appreciate any help offer.

**Update**

I have create a table as follows:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Acronym   |        ???           |      Meaning (?)                                                                                                                                         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      LAN     |  Local Area Network  | supplies networking capability to a group of computers in close proximity to each other such as in an office building, a school, or a home.              |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What would be the header name to replace the "???"?

And also, would the header name "Meaning" be suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An acronym is also an abbreviation, and your table would be better headed 'Abbreviation' rather than 'Acronym' because you may have non-acronyms like ADSL.

In fact, if this is a glossary that might contain non-abbreviations like Bandwidth ([for example](http://www.proprofs.com/mwiki/index.php/Network%2B_Glossary_%26_Acronyms), then 'Terms' is a better heading.

For the second heading you could use 'Meaning', and 'Description' in the third.

Alternatively, merge the second and third columns, or do away with the headings altogether; it's quite clear from the context what's in the table.

Comment: Good Explanation Hugo. I will mark your answer as the correct one if no one can come out with a better answer.

Comment: You can also vote up all the answers you find useful.

Comment: Definitely. but I prefer to put a tick on the answer as it gives 15 points to the person who helped me. (Upvote only give the person 10 points)

Comment: Hi Hugo, your answer is mark as correct as promised.

Comment: Yes, I found it useful. Also, I find that English Stack Exchange can learn quite a lot of useful English words - thanks to the whole community sharing their knowledge. Also, would like to thanks each and everyone who help to answer my questions too.

Answer (score 1):

The "short form" is, in this case, an acronym. See [Difference between an acronym and abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation)

The "long form" is not a backronym; that term is used when the long form is invented based on the acronym, often for humorous effect (for example, Ford = "Fix Or Repair Daily").

I'm not sure that there's a good, obvious word for the "long form." If you're preparing a Table of Acronyms and Abbreviations, as is sometimes required in technical documentation, I'd probably use "Meaning" as the heading for the "long form" column.

Comment: Fiat:  "Fix it again, Tony"

Comment: I wish to use "meaning" but imo, I think "meaning", for our example "LAN" would be "supplies networking capability to a group of computers in close proximity to each other such as in an office building, a school, or a home." So, I will need another word to replace 'Long Form'

Comment: Can you give an example of the context where you need a word for the long form? Is it a table heading, or a sentence, or what? Usually you can write "LAN is an acronym for Local Area Network" or "Local Area Network (abbreviated LAN)" without needing an explicit term for the long form.

Comment: @coneslayer For your information, yes, it is used in a table heading. I have reflect your comments into my question and hope that will clear some doubts.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Abbreviation" could mean more as Hugo suggested, and should be used here.
2. I've found "full name" and "full form" used quite often on the web. A mere "term" sounds also fine to me.
3. IMHO, "definition" may be more suitable than "meaning" in the context.

Comment: So, should I use 'phrase' to replace the 'long form'?

Comment: @LarryMorries That could be an option, but I'm not sure you can call it a phrase when you address technical terms like Local Area Network.

Answer (score 0):

My Merriam-Webster Unabridged defines *acronym* as

> a word formed from the initial letter or letters of each of the
>   successive parts or major parts of a *compound term*

So *compound term* would be a good heading for that column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

For your table, I would use the heading "Expansion" on the second column, and change the third column's heading to "Description".