# Proper capitalization of commonly used acronyms and initialisms

Tags: capitalization, acronyms, initialisms

I was always under impression, that acronyms ought to be written all caps. However reading [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/) site very often I see some of the common acronyms written as proper names (first cap). For example *"Nato"* instead of *"NATO"*.

I know that BBC is quite strict in proper English usage, so what would be the reason behind this?

Comment: I think many people (and some dictionaries) now consider "laser" to be a noun (that originated as an acronym). Interestingly the BBC News site always refers to the BBC as "BBC" and not "Bbc", however some acronyms are represented inconsistently, e.g. PETA (People for the Ethical Treatment of Animals) is written as either "Peta" or "PETA" depending on the article.

Comment: @Nathan With "BBC" you have to pronounce the individual letters, whereas with "LASER" it reads like a regular word. This makes it easier to treat "laser" like just another noun. In addition to this, it is not essential to know what "LASER" stands for to know what it is. That's just my take on why some acronyms have a tendency to evolve into lowercase usage while others do not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BBC is not as rigid about these matters as some other bodies. For example, it was recently written that the BBC had standardised on "CE" rather than "AD" for denoting years -- but in fact the BBC simply doesn't have a set of rigid standards for such things.

The [Guardian Style Guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/a), however, states:

> Use all capitals if an abbreviation is pronounced as the individual
>   letters: BBC, VAT, etc; if it is an acronym (pronounced as a word)
>   spell out with initial capital, eg Nasa, Nato, unless it can be
>   considered to have entered the language as an everyday word, such as
>   awol, laser and, more recently, asbo, pin number and sim card. Note
>   that pdf and plc are lowercase.

There is no universal rule; the Guardian's style guide is just one set of rules you can choose. The important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: +1. The online [Guardian style guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/a) is more up-to-date than the 2004 PDF.

Comment: Would be -1 to the Guardian Style Guide for "pin *number*", but the entry for "pin" does acknowledge the duplication.

Comment: It could be argued that "pin number" has entered everyday usage, tautology or not.

Comment: +1 purely for *the BBC is not as rigid...as some*. They have some "general" guidelines (don't overuse cliches, etc.) but nothing at all so detailed and prescriptive as even the Guardian Style Guide - which is positively cursory compared to [CMOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)

Comment: Seems pretty inconsistent; I thought most people pronounce VAT as vat, which would imply it being spelled as Vat according to their rules. (I could be wrong about the pronunciation, since I'm in the US, but that's what I've always heard people call it.)

Comment: VAT is more often pronounced "vee ay tee", although you do sometimes hear "vat" too.

Answer (score 6):

The BBC News Styleguide (March 2003, [pdf](http://www2.media.uoa.gr/lectures/linguistic_archives/academic_papers0506/notes/stylesheets_3.pdf)) says:

> **Abbreviations & acronyms**
>
> *One should not aim
> at being possible to
> understand but at
> being impossible to
> misunderstand.*
> **Quintilian**
>
> Just because you know what NACRO means, and
> the people you’ve discussed the story with know
> what it means, it doesn’t follow that the majority of
> your audience know. Assume nothing. Some short
> forms such as NATO, CIA, BBC, ITV,AA and RAC
> are well known and need no explanation, but think
> twice before using others. If you introduce the likes
> of BECTU, HSBC, RNIB, RTZ,ACAS and the BMA
> into your scripts without saying what they mean,
> you are virtually inviting some listeners or viewers
> to turn off. It’s usually better to give the full name of
> an organisation at first reference and then use its
> short form later.

It doesn't explicitly say to capitalise or not, but all these examples are given in upper case, including NATO.

As slim pointed out, the [Guardian style guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/a) says to always take an initial cap for pronounced words:

> Use all capitals if an abbreviation is pronounced as the individual letters: BBC, VAT, etc; if it is an acronym (pronounced as a word) spell out with initial capital, eg Nasa, Nato, unless it can be considered to have entered the language as an everyday word, such as awol, laser and, more recently, asbo, pin number and sim card. Note that pdf and plc are lowercase.

This sometimes looks a bit strange in print, with unfamiliar acronyms rendered as words,  even when the organisation in question and most people use all capitals.

My advice is to follow your style guide (if you have one), or decide per acronym whether to capitalise based on how the organisation or owner writes it, and based upon popular usage. And thereafter be consistent.

[NATO](http://www.nato.int) themselves use all capitals, and this is also the [most common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=NATO,Nato,nato&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image: Ngram showing NATO is much more common than Nato]

But the BBC have been using [Nato](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&btnmeta_news_search=1&q=nato%20site:bbc.co.uk&oq=nato%20site:bbc.co.uk&aq=f&aqi=d1d-o1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1932l6935l0l7087l27l25l0l18l0l1l314l1594l0.1.3.2l6l0) more recently. Perhaps they have decided it is well known enough that it can be written like this, in a similar way that LASER and RADAR have become naturalised as laser and radar.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the writer felt that it was now widely enough understood to be written as a normal word. The UK newspaper ‘The Times’ did the same as long ago as 1966:

> President Kekkonen's proposals for a neutral ‘Fenno-Scandia’, to
>   include not only Finland and Sweden but also Norway and perhaps
>   Denmark if they were prepared to leave Nato.

‘The Independent’ did so in 2001:

> Soldiers have been pouring into the city to reinforce Nato-led
>   peace-keepers.

*Nato-ish* and *Nato-ism* have also been found.

Comment: Tangent comment: In Swedish, a common rule is "if it's spelled out letter by letter, capitalize it. Otherwise treat is as a word." Hence SAS and radar.

Answer (score 3):

Per @Nohat's answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation), there's no universally-accepted definition of "acronym", but personally I normally only use it if the "initialism" spells out a pronouncable "word", such as *Nato*.

It's quite normal for well-known acronyms *by my definition* not to be capitalised at all (eg - *laser*). The first letter is capitalised as normal if the acronym is in fact a proper noun.