# Conversion of all-cap acronyms to first letter only; when did NASA become Nasa?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

The BBC will often refer to well recognized organizations named by an acronym by capitalizing only the first letter. For example, the [National Aeronautics and Space Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA) written as all capitals in the US as *NASA* is written as *Nasa* on the [BBC news website](https://www.bbc.com/news/topics/c77jz3mdmnxt/nasa) as is [*Nato* instead of NATO](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-18023383) for the North Atlantic Treaty Organization.

When did it become commonplace to convert all capital acronyms to first-letter only? Has this been done for quite a while and I never noticed, or is this a more recent occurrence?

I noticed that it's not a universal practice, it's still written as *NASA* in

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nasa

> Definition of NASA in English: (in the US) National Aeronautics and Space Administration.

https://public.oed.com/blog/september-2017-update-new-words-notes/

> An exoplanet is a planet which orbits a star other than the sun, also known as an extrasolar planet. The word is attested from 1992, around the time that the existence of the first exoplanets was confirmed. In the years since, advances in technology, and in particular the launch of the Kepler space telescope, have led to the discovery of thousands of exoplanets; according to NASA, the number now exceeds 3,500.

Comment: It didn't change from one to the other. Different authorities have different standards and guidelines for what letters should be capitalized in an abbreviation or initialism; [BBC Style for abbreviations](https://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/en/articles/art20130702112133548) is to use *lower case with an initial cap for acronyms where you would normally pronounce the set of letters as a word (eg Aids, Nafta, Nasa, Opec, Apec)*. This question is previously answered at *[Proper capitalization of commonly used acronyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51924)*

Comment: Sounds good to me.