# "Short for" vs. "Stands for"

Tags: expressions, differences, idioms, word-usage

1. US stands for "the United States".
2. US is short for "the United States".

What are the subtle differences between them?

Comment: The US is a slightly tricky one, as it can be used as both: a better example might be **GB stands for "Great Britain", Britain is short for "Great Britain"**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Stands for" is normally used when you are explaining an acronym or initialism, and may also be used for other forms of [abbreviation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation):

> *USA* stands for "United States of America"
>   *Laser* stands for "Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation"
>   *CENTPACCOM* stands for "Central Pacific Command".

"Is short for" is more normally used for non-initialism, non-acronym abbreviations, and is also the standard way to explain a nickname:

> *[NORAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command)* is short for "North American Aerospace Defense Command"
>   *Peg* is short for "Margaret"
>   *Max* is short for "Maximillian"

Comment: Why is NORAD used with "short for" but not "stand for"

Comment: @Ooker or conversely why  *CENTPACCOM stands for "Central Pacific Command"*?

Comment: @ChrisH yeah, I would like to ask that question too

Comment: @ooker and Chris, both of those could go with either "stands for" or "is short for".  Personally I prefer "is short for" since (a) they are pronounced as words and (b) the short forms include more than just a single letter from each word in the corresponding long form (NOR-A-D).  (If they had gone with a different abbreviation, then I could say "NADS *stands for* North American Defense System, but it *is short for* gonads.")

Comment: I've put an edit in for this, as NORAD really isn't a short form, it's an abbreviation... just a composite one (NOR Aviation Defence, where NOR is itself a short form for Northern Command)

Comment: @JonStory, "is short for" can be used on abbreviations or short forms, so NORAD is still a valid example.  Also, wikipedia disagrees with you as to what "NORAD" actually stands for.  (Although I also had it wrong originally, so I had to edit the post.)

Answer (score 2):

"Short for" implies that its shorter. "Stands for" just means that A stands in place for B as a verbal alias.

Because these uses go beyond acronyms, sometimes in conversation you will hear things like

> "Cookie"? That's short for "the team cook".

or:

> "The silver chicken"? That stands for "colonel".

or even, sarcastically (especially in the military, government or other large organizations with their own doublespeak):

> "Subdaylight, gravity assisted, vertical insertion"? That's short for
>   "night jump".

In this sense "stands for" is directly replaceable with "means" or "is a/the", whereas "short for" tends to indicate a convenience name which is either actually shorter or is easier to pronounce. In common usage, the difference between the two is often negligible to non-existant.

Comment: I wish someone would explain what about this answer is deserving downvotes instead of just subjecting it to drivebys.

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent expressions, but the concept is easily understood (at least in the U.S.) and more usually appears as, "the United States (hereafter, U.S.)..."